# How to get a concurrent method

Tags: methods, go, goroutine

How to get a concurrent method?

```
type test struct {
    foo uint8
    bar uint8
}

func NewTest(arg1 string) (*test, os.Error) {...}

func (self *test) Get(str string) ([]byte, os.Error) {...}
```

I think that all code for method `Get()` should be put inner of `go func()`, and then to use a channel.

```
func (self *test) Get(str string) ([]byte, os.Error) {
    go func() {
        // Code for this method.
    }()
}
```

- Would there be a problem if it's called another method from `Get()`? Or would it also has to be concurrent?

Comment: To tell the truth, your question is a bit difficult to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [An example package](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#An_example_package) section in The Go Language Specification, which is a complete Go package that implements a concurrent prime sieve, using go statements and channels.

For a detailed description of how it works, see the Go Tutorial section on [Prime numbers](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html). Also, look at the Go Tutorial section on [Multiplexing](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html).

Read the Effective Go section on [Concurrency](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency).

Finally, read the relevant sections of The Go Language Specification e.g. the sections on [Go statements](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Go_statements), [Channel types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Channel_types), and [Select statements](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Select_statements).

Yes, you can call another method from your Get() method. Since a method call is not a concurrent go statement, it will execute immediately, before executing the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

The way you get concurrency in go is to use the keyword "go" in front of functions you want to execute concurrently:

func bar () { ... }

func foo () {
  go bar()
  go bar()
  go bar()
... code that waits for all the bars to close ...
}

That's all it takes to run 3 bars at the same time.  PS: You might want to provide an example in a language you are familiar with, C++ / Perl / Python / whatever since the go code fragment you included wasn't much help.  I realize you probably speak English better than I speak your native language, but you might also want to get some assistance formulating your question more clearly.

Hotei